# Bash. ошибка синтаксиса: неожиданный конец файла

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

строка 21: ошибка синтаксиса: неожиданный конец файла.

```
#!/bin/bash




read x;

if [ $x > 1 ]
then echo "Good!" 

else if [ $x < 1]
then echo "Bad"

fi

exit 0;
```

Comment: Путь /bin/bash - правильный

Comment: тут всего 16 строк, что-то не договариваете

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все баш правильно ругается. if - два штуки, а fi - один. Вот и ругается. Исправленный вариант

```
#!/bin/bash

read x

if [ $x > 1 ]
then echo "Good!" 
else if [ $x < 1]
then echo "Bad"
fi
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 8):

можно, как справедливо указано в предыдущем ответе, добавить недостающий оператор `fi`.

а можно вместо этого заменить операторы `else if` на один оператор `elif`. тогда одного оператора `fi` будет достаточно.